# Jquery/Javascript remove duplicate parameters in a url string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my url string, I am trying to break down the parameters and get the value for "q"           parameter.

```
a) http://myserver.com/search?q=bread?topic=14&sort=score
b) http://myserver.com/search?q=bread?topic=14&sort=score&q=cheese

how do i use Jquery/JavaScript to get "q" value?
```

for case a), i can use string split or use jquery getUrlParam to get q value = bread

for case b), when there are duplicates how do i retrieve the q value at the end, when there are multiple "q" params

Comment: this question may help u : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in pure javascript, try

```
function getParameterByName(name) {

    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)')
                    .exec(window.location.search);

    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));

}
```

**[Reference](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/bujs-1-getparameterbyname/)**

in jQuery see this plugin

### https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser

### UPDATE

when u get array of all query string then to remove duplicate from an array via jQuery try **[unique](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)**  or see this plugin

### http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/array-remove-duplicates

Comment: The code you provided will get the first `q=`, not the last `q=`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use a regular expression. For example, we might have this string:

```
var str = 'http://myserver.com/search?q=bread&topic=14&sort=score&q=cheese';
```

Find the search portion of the URL by stripping everything from the beginning to the first question mark.

```
var search = str.replace(/^[^?]+\?/, '');
```

Set up a pattern to capture all `q=something`.

```
var pattern = /(^|&)q=([^&]*)/g;
var q = [], match;
```

And then execute the pattern.

```
while ((match = pattern.exec(search))) {
    q.push(match[2]);
}
```

After that, q will contain all the `q` parameters. In this case, `[ "bread", "cheese" ]`.

Then you can use any of `q`.

If you only care about the last one, you can replace the `q.push` line with `q = match[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use `getUrlParam` for both, but you have to handle the second case's return value as an array with multiple values (at least in the [getUrlParam code](http://code.google.com/p/linked-data-api/source/browse/trunk/examples/visualisations/gov-structure/js/jquery.getUrlParam.js?r=241) I'm looking at).

Answer (score 0):

getUrlParam('q') should return an array. Try to get those values with this code:

```
values = $.getUrlParam('q');

// use the following code
first_q_value = values[0];
second_q_value = values[1];
```